# How to update image in slider when i change image with same name

Tags: php, css, slider

I have slider like this in my html

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 swiper-container swiper1">

            <div class="swiper-wrapper">    
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <a href="produk/koleksi-jam"><img class="live1"></a>
                </div>


            <!-- Add Pagination -->
            <div class="swiper-pagination swiper-pagination1"></div>
        </div>  
    </div>
```

i use swiper slider to load the image and the resource of image i save in css with class name live1

sometime i have to change the image to the new image

I took the initiative compared to having to change the name of the image in CSS, I better replace it with a new image that has the same name.

but I have a problem, the browser sometimes has to press ctrl + f5 first to refresh the display if not the image always uses the previous assets.

the question is how can I immediately change the image without ctrl + f5 first to see the new image?

Comment: *Please refer this [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135826/348234) to learn about accepting answer. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.*

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You will always gotta use `Control + F5` if you wanna ignore cache. Another way would be removing it manually from the browser.

Welcome to Internet.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the same name as old file, you have to clear cache as it reference to same name in it's memory.
So try using different name of the image or try using a name which will be unique all the time so you will never have to hard reload the page or even you can prevent caching mechanism of browser.

Here are the options you can choose:

**(1) Add a unique cache-busting query parameter to the image URL,**

such as:

**newImage.src = "image.jpg?t=" + new Date().getTime();**

**Pros**: 100% reliable, quick & easy to understand and implement.

**Cons**: Bypasses caching altogether, meaning unnecessary delays and bandwidth use whenever the image doesn't change between views. Will potentially fill browser cache (and any intermediate caches) with many, many copies of exactly the same image! Also, requires modifying image URL.

**When to use**: Use when image is constantly changing, such as for a live webcam feed. If you use this method, make sure to serve the images themselves with Cache-control: no-cache HTTP headers!!! (Often this can be set up using a .htaccess file). Otherwise you'll be progressively filling caches up with old versions of the image!

**(2) Or you can choose to prevent caching:**

To turn off caching, you can send the following response header. In addition, see also the Expires and Pragma headers.

**Cache-Control: no-store**

Hope it works!